# Normalising a CGFloat Array to UIView frame height

Tags: swift, swift4

I am plotting an array of CGFloat values within a UIBezierPath. Now I want to Normalise the values so the max value of the array will occupy the whole height.

So far

```
let scaleFactor = (waveView.frame.height) * readFile.maxValue

for point in readFile.points {        
    let nextPoint = CGPoint(x: soundPath.currentPoint.x + sampleSpace, y: middleY - (point * scaleFactor) - 1.0)

    soundPath.addLine(to: nextPoint)
    soundPath.move(to: nextPoint)        
}
```

But it does not seem to work...

EDIT 
ReadFile:

```
class ReadFile {
public enum ReadFileError:Error{
    case errorReading(String)

}

/* Player Interval Measured in Miliseconds (By now..) */
var beginPosition:Int32 = 0
var endPosition:Int32 = 0

/* Sample Rate -> Default 48KHz */
var sampleRate:Double = 48000

var samplesSeconds:CGFloat = 5

var maxValue:CGFloat = 0
var points:[CGFloat] = []
```

}

And

```
sampleSpace = 0.2
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? What is the output?

Comment: it just plots very big values

Comment: It would help if you could show more code, such as the declaration of `readFile` & `sampleSpace`

Comment: does the update help?

Comment: `waveView.frame.height * readFile.maxValue` will give you a value larger than your total height if `maxValue` is larger than 1. Try `waveView.frame.height / readFile.maxValue` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Andy for your answer but I have finally figured it out.

I am drawing a sound wave so it has positives and negatives values.

heightMax = waveView.frame.height/2

Applying a rule of three (Spanish translation) I end up with this:

```
    func drawSoundWave(windowLength:Int32){

    // Drawing code
    print("\(logClassName): Drawing!!!")
    print("\(logClassName): points COUNT = \(readFile.points.count)")

    let soundPath = UIBezierPath()
    soundPath.lineWidth = lineWidth
    soundPath.move(to: CGPoint(x:0.0 , y: middleY))

    print("\(logClassName) max ")
    for point in readFile.points{

        let normalizedHeight:CGFloat = (waveView.frame.height * point) / (2 * readFile.maxValue)
        let nextPoint = CGPoint(x: soundPath.currentPoint.x + sampleSpace, y: middleY - (normalizedHeight))

        soundPath.addLine(to: nextPoint)
        soundPath.move(to: nextPoint)

    }

    let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    trackLayer.path = soundPath.cgPath

    waveView.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)

    trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
    trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound

}
```

where

```
let normalizedHeight:CGFloat = (waveView.frame.height * point) / (2 * readFile.maxValue)
```

is the normalize value given a readFile.maxValue and waveView.frame.height